# Unexpected behaviour when scaling projection matrix in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;

uniform mat4 viewMatrix_;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix_;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix_;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix_*viewMatrix_*modelMatrix_*vec4(vertexPos, 1.0);
}
```

I am trying to scale my points by scaling the model matrix as multiples of the identity.
Ie,

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f)*scale;
shaderProgram_->SetUniformMat4("modelMatrix_", model);
```

But I seem to get no change at all. If I add a uniform float and multiply the vertex vector position by the scale, then I get my desired effect.

If the scale is 0, the vertices disappear as expected.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f)*scale` does not result in a valid scaling matrix. A valid scaling matrix would contain the scaling value on the first three elements of the diagonal, but have a value of 1.0 in the last diagonal element, e.g.:

```
s 0 0 0
0 s 0 0
0 0 s 0
0 0 0 1
```

while your code produces a matrix where all diagonal elements are set to the scaling factor, e.g.:

```
s 0 0 0
0 s 0 0
0 0 s 0
0 0 0 s <-- check here
```

The reason why you then don't see much of a difference is that now also the w value gets scaled, which means that the whole operation cancels out after the perspective divide.

If you need a scaling matrix, I highly recommend to use

```
glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(scale, scale, scale));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you scale the *whole* diagonal of your identity matrix, while in fact you only need to scale first 3 values on this diagonal.

```
     [ s 0 0 0 ]           [ s 0 0 0 ]
Need [ 0 s 0 0 ]       Not [ 0 s 0 0 ]
this [ 0 0 s 0 ]      this [ 0 0 s 0 ]
     [ 0 0 0 1 ]           [ 0 0 0 s ]
```